# Can I style an element with JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Am trying to work out a fee progress bar. I have calculated the percentage of the width of the progress with JavaScript and it's a variable `z`. So I am trying to style the element with the variable `z` and it's not working when I add `%` to it. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="mybar">
    <div class="myprogress" id="progress">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    window.onload=function(){
      var fee=document.getElementById("fee").innerHTML;
      var bill=document.getElementById("bill").innerHTML;
      var y=(fee/bill);
      var z=(y*100);
      document.getElementById("progress").style.width="z%";
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [string template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

like this:

```
document.getElementById("progress").style.width=`${z}%`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `z` is a variable, and you want to create a string with the `%` sign afterwards, you need to append them:

```
 document.getElementById("progress").style.width = z + '%';
```

Comment: or use template literal: `document.getElementById("progress").style.width=\`${z}%\`;`

Answer (score 1):

A Summary of available ways to style using JavaScript.

## Plain Javascript

Either concatenate z and the Percent sign:

```
document.getElementById("progress").style.width = z + "%";
```

Or use string template literals:

```
document.getElementById("progress").style.width=`${z}%`;
```

## JQuery

```
$("#progress").css("width", z + "%");
```

or

```
$("#progress").css("width", `${z}%`);
```

Comment: @JasonPerchingBird You can accept the answer you find the most helpful using the grey tick-mark next to it...